# Stirling numbers of the first kind: A combinatorial interpretation problem

Tags: combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

One of the most popular interpretations of the unsigned Stirling number of the first kind ${n\brack n-k}$ is the number of permutations of $n$ elements with exactly $n-k$ permutation cycles. I have searched the literature for a combinatorial interpretation for $n{n\brack n-k}$ but have not found anything yet. Can someone help? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: In terms of what do you want it? That is just saying that you have a permutation with $n-k$ cycles and a selected element in the domain.